# DB2 SQL PL CONTINE HANDLER DOES NOT CATCH ERROR

Tags: db2, sql-pl

Why does the exception handler not work in the following example ?

```
db2 => BEGIN
db2 (cont.) =>   DECLARE YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID VARCHAR(36);
db2 (cont.) =>   DECLARE FUNCTION_DEFINITION VARCHAR(256);
db2 (cont.) =>
db2 (cont.) =>   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42884' BEGIN
db2 (cont.) =>     SELECT  LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),8)
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT '-'
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4)
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT '-'
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4)
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT '-'
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4)
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT '-'
db2 (cont.) =>     CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),12)
db2 (cont.) =>     INTO YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID
db2 (cont.) =>     FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
db2 (cont.) =>   END;
db2 (cont.) =>
db2 (cont.) =>   SELECT YADAMU.YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID()
db2 (cont.) =>     INTO YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID
db2 (cont.) => FROM  SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
db2 (cont.) =>
db2 (cont.) =>   SET FUNCTION_DEFINITION = 'CREATE FUNCTION YADAMU.YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID() RETURNS VARCHAR(36) DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION CONTAINS SQL RETURN ''' CONCAT YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID CONCAT '''';
db2 (cont.) =>   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FUNCTION_DEFINITION;
db2 (cont.) => END;
db2 (cont.) => /
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID" of type "FUNCTION"
having compatible arguments was found.  LINE NUMBER=19.  SQLSTATE=42884
db2 =>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Since you recreate the function every time and don't handle the corresponding error, when the function exists, I've added the `OR REPLACE` clause to the function definition. Note the absence of `;` at the end of the compound statement.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID VARCHAR(36);
  DECLARE FUNCTION_DEFINITION VARCHAR(256);
  
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42884', SQLSTATE '56098' 
  BEGIN
    SELECT  LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),8)
    CONCAT '-'
    CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4)
    CONCAT '-'
    CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4)
    CONCAT '-'
    CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4)
    CONCAT '-'
    CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),12)
    INTO YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
  END;

  PREPARE S1 FROM 'SET ? = YADAMU.YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID()';
  EXECUTE S1 INTO YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID;
  
  SET FUNCTION_DEFINITION = 'CREATE OR REPLACE YADAMU.FUNCTION YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID() RETURNS VARCHAR(36) DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION CONTAINS SQL RETURN ''' CONCAT YADAMU_INSTANCE_ID CONCAT '''';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FUNCTION_DEFINITION;
END
/
```

Comment: Thx - this worked, once the typo was fixed. I'd cut the code down when I pasted this, in the real world, I drop and re-create the entire schema after preserving the psudeo-guid. Still not sure why my original code failed, when the schema was dropped. However swithcin to prepare/execute seems to fix the issue.